# VHDL Compare not working in hardware but works in simulation

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

Hi guys I have the following VHDL which isn't doing what it suppose to in hardware but it does work in simulation. Basically I have a counter and depending on the count I want certain data to be output I implemented the mux as following:

```
write_data  <=  
('1' & '0' & "1111"                                                              )  when (data_cnt_r < 1)  else             
('0' & '0' & "1111"                                                              ) when (data_cnt_r >= 1 and data_cnt_r < 2 ) else
('0' & '0' & "0000"                                                              ) when (data_cnt_r >= 2 and data_cnt_r < 3 ) else  
('0' & '0' & data_reg                                                        ) when (data_cnt_r >= 3  and data_cnt_r < 1027 ) else
('0' & '1' & CRC16_o(63) & CRC16_o(47) & CRC16_o(31) & CRC16_o(15) ) when (data_cnt_r >= 1027  and data_cnt_r < 1043 ) else 
('0' & '0' & "1111");
```

The problem I am getting is that when the count is 1043 I see the CRC output instead of seeing "1111" for the last line in the code. In the simulation it works like I would expect. Is there a better way to write this? Any ideas why the discrepancy?

*EDIT More details as requested:

I'm using

```
   use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
```

data_cnt is a free runnig counter, everything is std_logic_vector or std_logic

```
    signal data_cnt_r       : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0); -- 12 bit counter
```

write_data goes to a BUFIO and it is also a standard logic vector

Comment: You may want to consider using (n = 0) instead of (n < 1). Also, assuming two state logic for data_cnt_r, the first condition in all of the cases is redundant.

Comment: what is the datatype of data_cnt_r?

Comment: I don't think the problem is just on this line. I'd probably need to see more code. Normally discrepancies between simulation and hardware are down to things like incorrect sensitivity lists, but this isn't in a process. They also should come up as warnings during sim/syn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening near your other transitions? (1027, 3, 2, 1)
is this in a process block or is it asynch?
is data_cnt_r an unsigned? What about data_reg and CRC values? I assume both std_logic_vectors?

We need a little more context

you could try explicitly adding a transition to see if it helps ala:

```
('0' & '1' & CRC_stor)  when (data_cnt_r >= 1027 and data_cnt_r < 1043 ) else 
('0' & '0' & "1111"  )  when (data_cnt_r = 1043) else
('0' & '0' & "1111"  );
```

if this is actually in a clocked process block you might see the CRC values in write_data a clock cycle later but then you would also see this problem around your other transitions (they would all update a cycle behind data_cnt_r)

You might be getting unexpected logical errors if its in an unclocked process block

Also this is a little easier to read.

```
CRC_stor <= CRC16_o(63) & CRC16_o(47) & CRC16_o(31) & CRC16_o(15)

write_data  <=  
   ('1' & '0' & "1111"  )  when (data_cnt_r = 0) else             
   ('0' & '0' & "1111"  )  when (data_cnt_r = 1) else
   ('0' & '0' & "0000"  )  when (data_cnt_r = 2) else  
   ('0' & '0' & data_reg)  when (data_cnt_r >= 3    and data_cnt_r < 1027 ) else
   ('0' & '1' & CRC_stor)  when (data_cnt_r >= 1027 and data_cnt_r < 1043 ) else 
   ('0' & '0' & "1111"  );
```

Comment: Good points, thank you all, I appreciate everyones feedback and help, I resolved this issue. I had two problems. 1) I wasn't registering the output, 2) The output clock should be 90 out of phase with data going out of the FPGA so the device clocks in correctly.